# Big Omega/Oh Notation (Application)

Tags: notation, asymptotics

For clarity; I use the following definitions (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), in my question:

Big Omicron: $f(n)=O(g(n))$. Formal definition: $\exists k >0,\exists n_{0}, \forall n>n_{0}: |f(n)| \leq k |g(n)| $.

Big Omega: $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$. Formal definition: $\exists k >0,\exists n_{0}, \forall n>n_{0}: f(n) \geq k g(n) $.

Property 1: $f(n)=O(g(n)) \Leftrightarrow g(n)=\Omega(f(n))$

Property 2: $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ and $g(n)=\Omega(h(n))$, then $f(n)=\Omega(h(n))$

---

Now consider the following: $v(n)=v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n)$. $v_{1}(n)$ and $v_{2}(n)$ are positive for all $n>0$. $v_{3}(n)$
is negative for all $n>0$. It is also true that $v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n) \geq 0$ for all $n>0$.

Using the definitions stated above, is the following correct:

$v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)=O(v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n))$ because $|v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)| \leq k|v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n)|$

and, because of property 1, we can write

$v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n)=\Omega(v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n))$

and because of property 2 it holds that

$v(n)=v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n)=\Omega(v_{1}(n))$

My guess is that something is wrong because it feels odd to lower-bound the function $v(n)$ without considering the negative term $v_{3}(n)$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)=O(v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n))$ because $|v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)| \leq k|v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n)|$

This is false. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Also, if you want to be precise, it is better to treat the Landau notations as denoting **sets** of expressions, and write for instance $n \in O(n^2)$ and $O(n^2) \subseteq O(n^3)$, as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is not obvious to me why $v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)=O(v_{1}(n)+v_{2}(n)+v_{3}(n))$ is false. I thought this would follow directly from the definition of big Omicron? Because $|v_{3}(n)|\geq0$.

Comment: @RitaV: Firstly, you did not specify what is $k$, so your statement does not make sense. Secondly, even if I interpret your statement to attempt to make it line up with the definition of big-O, it is false. Anyway you should always try examples. For example if you claim that $|x+y| \le |x+y+z|$ for any $x,y \ge 0$ and $z \le 0$, it should be easy for you to find a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue.